# Multi-Output Regression with Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, regression

I am trying to do a multi-output regression using TensorFlow. I have got a dataset in Excel which includes a column of input points and 2 columns of output.[image: You can see it here.]

I converted all numbers to NumPy objects. And I am trying to do a basic regression but accuracy is always 1.0, I also want to draw a graph but dunno where to start. Could Anyone please help? My code is here:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.activations import relu


training_data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yeni klasör\training_data.xlsx',sheet_name="i1-o2")
training_data_X = training_data['i1']
traindataX = np.array(training_data_X)
training_data_Y = training_data[['o1','o2']]
traindataY = np.array(training_data_Y)
testing_data = data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yeni klasör\testing_data.xlsx',sheet_name="i1-o2")
testing_data_X = testing_data['i1']
testing_data_Y = testing_data[['o1','o2']]
testdataX = np.array(testing_data_X)
testdataY = np.array(testing_data_Y)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.tanh))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.tanh))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(traindataX,traindataY,epochs=500)

val_loss,val_acc = model.evaluate(testdataX,testdataY)
print(val_loss,val_acc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a *regression* setting, where accuracy is **meaningless** (it is meaningful only in *classification* settings).

Simply remove the `metrics=['accuracy']` argument from your model compilation, so that `model.evaluate` returns the loss only (discard also `val_acc`).

See the SO thread [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577) for more details.